# Facebook post to wall JavaScript not allowing me to change the "Say something..." text

Tags: javascript, facebook, web, social-networking

I am trying to change the "Say something..." text part of a post to feed function of the FB.ui

All else shows but it doesn't change the text in the text area.

My code is below :

```
function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'http://solarhelper.net',
      picture: 'http://solarhelper.net/icon',
      name: 'Find your result using Solar Helper',
      caption: 'Click the link to download the app or get your result online.',
      description: 'I could save ' + incomeYear25 + ' over 25 years and save ' + totalCO2Level + ' tonnes of CO2!',
      message: 'Testing'
    };

    function callback(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            alert('Post was published.');
        } else {
            alert('Post was not published.');
        }
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);

  }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have updated the question to show the entire function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're not and you will not be able to change this part of a dialog.

I suppose this prevention should restrict event more spam ?

Comment: I have built a iPhone app using Appcelerator, this uses JavaScript also and I have been able to change that text there. Also looking at some examples on the web it sugests that it could be done too. It's just not working for me. If you look at the example images used on the Facebook documentation it sugests this could be done too http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: Trust me, this is not possible. Try to go to the link specified by documentation (`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=123050457758183&
  link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response`), you'll see that you won't achieve it

Comment: @user1136076 Yeah, Martin is correct. You can use `message` with requests, but not with feed posts.

Comment: It shows on the Facebook documentation an example of doing just this but it doesn't seem to work. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/

Comment: @user yeah, it probably worked before. It looks removed now, though

Comment: If I helped you, please tick this answer as correct on the left side